# No bar at the bottom on Gnome after installing some Debian packages

Tags: debian, gnome, aptitude

A little bit back I tried to install a package with aptitude. One of its substitutions deleted gnome and many other packages. The bar at the bottom is gone basically, anyone know how to bring the bar back, and hopefully all the other missing packages that are in Debian without reinstall Debian?

Answer (score 2):

Aptitude logs what it does into `/var/log/aptitude` and/or `/var/log/apt/*`. Looking through those files will be the quickest way for you to find out what got *uninstalled* so you can try restoring them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want gnome just try to install that (with `aptitude install gnome`), it might tell you that it conflicts with something else (whatever it was that made it remove gnome in the first place), but take that from there then.